# Is onpage modal better or external?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

There are two plugins that I can work with in ruby on rails. One is called fancybox and the other is a bootstrap modal. There are two different ways it works. If I use fancybox, I will have to create another view which will server as a template and the modal will fetch data.

EX: I have a login button `/home/index` contains a link. When the link is pressed, it loads the template from `/home/login`, `/login/modal`, or anywhere else I decide to use it.

On the other hand, the information and data of the bootstrap modal is located on the same page. If there is a link and it is pressed, it loads the data from the same view.

For fancybox you have to create a separate view, but for bootstrap you have to have all of the content on one page.

I was wondering what the pros and cons of each and which would ultimately be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For bootstrap modals, you do not have to load the data that will be in your modal on the
>   same page.  On more than one occassion i have used jquery to do a
>   $.get and simply load the response html into the bootstrap modal body.
>   All you have to do is give the modal-body an id or use the .modal-body class.  See bottom of this answer for code example

**To answer your questions about pros and cons:**

**Loading from another view:**

PROS:

code is encapsulated in that view and can be easily reused and tested

if the resulting view is heavy or takes a while to load/process, your initial page load is not bogged down and the heavy load is only incurred when the user requests it

CONS:

code is in a seperate area and can be confusing for other people trying to follow

overkill for very simple views inside the modal

**Loading from same view**

PROS:

code is simple and easy to follow

CONS:

code cannot be reused and after you copy and paste a few times, maintenance nightmare

heavy loading code can bog down page when may not ever be viewed by user

*if interested, here is how i load twitter bootstrap modals from another view using jquery:*

```
$.post("myOtherView.aspx", null, function (response) {
    if (typeof console == "object") { console.log("Response: " + response); }
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(response);
});

$('#myModal').modal();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes things a little clearer. As for your code, its useful but not exactly what I am looking for. I will post another question about it.